# Questions about newsletters & warning message on my interface

Tags: emails

I would like to send an email to all the Architect Declare's French members.
Is it possible to do this in the form of a newsletter?

Moreover, it says this at the top of the interface when I connect to the site: "Your project config YAML files contain pending changes."
What does this mean?

Thanks in advance,
The administration of the Architects Declare's French website

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to send an email to all the Architect Declare's French members. Is it possible to do this in the form of a newsletter?

Craft doesn't have any newsletter-like features out of the box. You might want to take a look at the [Campaign plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/campaign).

> "Your project config YAML files contain pending changes." What does this mean?

Craft uses static YAML files to keep your site's content model (i.e. your fields, sections, categories etc) in sync between environments, as part of a concept called [project config](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/project-config.html). For example, the YAML files makes it possible for a developer to make changes to your site's content model locally on their machine, and then deploy and apply those changes to the production server without having to re-do them manually in that environment.

**The alert means that the project config YAML files currently on your web server, is out of sync with the project config currently in your site's database.** This could be due to a developer deploying changed YAML files to the web server, but without actually [applying](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/project-config.html#propagating-changes) the changes in those files. But, it could also be due to an error or misconfiguration somewhere, that has caused your database's config and the config in the YAML files to somehow fall out of sync.

You can inspect the changes (i.e. the difference between your database's config and the config in the YAML files) via the Project Config utility, which is found by clicking "Utilities" in the main menu inside Craft's control panel, and either **apply** or **discard** them.

However, you should be aware that applying or discarding YAML changes can potentially be *a very bad idea*, if a) you don't know why the project config is out of sync in the first place and/or b) you're not completely sure what will happen if you do apply or discard the changes in the YAML files.

Depending on the cause for the project config to be out of sync, and the actual "changes" contained in the file, both applying and discarding those changes could potentially be destructive. I'd very much recommend to try and figure out exactly why that alert started appearing before taking any action – in addition to backing up the database.